# Linux Alternatives to Windows Spiceworks?

Tags: free-software

I really like Spiceworks for managing our network at work; but there's a problem with it; it runs on Windows, and I don't want to have to buy a copy of Windows just so I can manage, ticketing, scans, etc on my home network.

Is there anything similar to this that can be run on Linux?

Comment: Spiceworks is a large application. What parts of it were you wanting to have going on in your home network? I'm assuming you wouldn't want stuff like asset management (which would be overkill, I would think) for a home network. Are you just looking for a ticketing system?

Comment: Asset management would be good too..

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you need asset management for your home network? Shouldn't it just be a matter of keeping track of 3-4 laptops and a linksys router or something on that level?

Comment: @slm Thanks, I wasn't quite sure what to call Spiceworks exactly, it seems like a bunch of different types of programs jammed into a single web interface.

Comment: Yeah the whole category of monitoring is a full time job 8-)

Comment: I'm gonna convert these comments to an A too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you never responded so I'll try my best to list FOSS alternatives for each system:

Asset Management:

- RackTables

Ticketing:

- OTRS
- eticket

Network Monitoring/Notification:

- Nagios
- Zabbix
- collectd

General Systems Management

- Spacewalk
- Katello
- Foreman+puppet
- Ubuntu Landscape

Also, fyi, some of the "General Systems Management" also provide inventory/asset management functions. They're not typically as advanced as specialized software, though.

Answer (score 2):

Am I interpreting this right? You want to control your home network(clients) like running a network scan, seeing network traffic, managing firewall?

If it is, then [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org) is the industry standard in IT infrastructure monitoring. **OR ** [Icinga](https://www.icinga.org/) which is a fork of Nagios, and is FOSS.

I think this may be kind of overkill but then you could also use OpenNMS.

Answer (score 0):

This list is probably the way to go:

- [Comparison of network monitoring systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems).

There are literally 100's of packages geared to monitoring the various aspects of your network/infrastructure. It's probably best to think about the actual things you'd like to monitor and then find a package that is suited to those things. Personally I've used Nagios. It's extremely popular but can be a bit of a steep learning curve. Plan on a week or so to grok it.

If you're looking for an out of the box solution [Fully Automated Nagios](http://www.fullyautomatednagios.org/) is a good compromise. Good docs and provide a decent frontend for setting up and managing Nagios.

Also take a look at the alternatives listed at [alternatives.to](http://alternativeto.net/):

- [Alternative applications to Spiceworks](http://alternativeto.net/software/spiceworks/)